# Complex derivative and the Jacobian

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have read in some lecture notes I found the following **statement**:

> The derivative of a function $f: A\subset \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$. if
>   it exists at a point $z:=(x,y)$, satisfies $f'(z)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)$.

If we consider the isomorphism of fields given by $a+bi\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} a &-b \\ b &a \end{bmatrix}$, then the statement above follows from the definition of a $2 \times 2$ Jacobian matrix.

However, we could easily define the isomorphism as $a+bi\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} a &b \\ -b &a \end{bmatrix}$, so that now $f'(z)=u_x(x,y)+iu_y(x,y)=u_x(x,y)-iv_x(x,y)$. Therefore, the isomorphism doesn't seem to prove in general the analytic statement above, which would make sense since an isomorphism is just a result about algebraic relabeling.

I have never seen the above statement before and am surprised that it's true. Could someone please tell me if it is in fact true in general and, if so, a brief explanation?

Comment: These are known as the cauchy riemann equations; look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations . In the section Conformal mapping, they mentioned the associated Jacobian matrix

Comment: @Ant Thank you. very helpful